# og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-opengraph

I have tried to set the proper og:image for hours now.
The Facebook debugger shows me that is finds the correct og:image
But then it is not used and it is throwing me the warning:

"og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. "

I have tried images in every possible format, every possible resolution, every possible size. I have tried with and without the width and height tags etc etc.

It keeps throwing me this ambitious error. Can someone please shed some light on this?

here are my tags:

```
<meta property=fb:app_id content=1385xxxxxxx>
<meta property=og:site_name content=AnyJobby>
<meta property=og:type content=website>
<meta property=og:url content=https://www.anyjobby.nl/>
<meta property=og:title content="AnyJobby - Vind een betrouwbare Jobber uit jouw buurt!">
<meta property=og:description content="Plaats gratis jouw klusje of karweitje op AnyJobby en ontvang direct biedingen van handige Jobbers uit de community.">
<meta property=og:image content="https://www.anyjobby.nl/social.png"/>
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.anyjobby.nl/social.png" /> 
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" /> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first og:image tag you have not closed the tag in quotations

Change it from:

```html
<meta property=og:image content="https://www.anyjobby.nl/social.png"/>
```

To:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.anyjobby.nl/social.png"/>
```